# In radar pulse analysis, why is the PRF of pulse not calculated using Fourier transform?

Tags: signal-analysis, radar, pulse

So, I am fairly new to this, but when going through books on Radar pulses, I noticed that quite often, a formula describing the frequency of the waveform is given. For example, the frequency of a Linear Frequency Modulated waveform is given to be estimated using the following:

$$f(t)=\frac{1}{2\pi}\frac{d(\pi kt^2)}{dt} $$

My question is, why can I not simply use the Fourier transform to get the band for the LFM and obtain its starting and ending frequency? Or even in the case of Barker Coded waveforms, why is the FFT not preferred for PRF finding? Would it cause any specific errors?

Comment: Two things: 1. PRF is typically pretty unrelated to the signal design – It's simply how often e.g. the $f(t)$ you drafted above repeats. 2. You seem to be confusing the mathematical description of a signal with how it's physically generated, and those are simply two different things!

Comment: However, I'm really not sure what you mean with "why can I not simply use the Fourier transform to get the band for the LFM": What do you mean with "the band"? What do you want to Fourier-transform, specifically, from which domain to another, for which purpose?

Comment: Why do you think you can't use the FFT, or any other spectral analysis tool?

Comment: @MarcusMüller Well, I was wondering if I can find the PRF from the Fourier transform? I was referring to the bandwidth of the signal as "The band". Is the PRF and frequency of the signal, not the same thing?

Comment: again, the PRF is "outside of the scope" of your formula. No, they are very different things. A PRF of 5 kHz says "I send 5000 pulses a second", and each of these pulses could have, for example, a 2 GHz bandwidth. These two numbers are practically unrelated.

Comment: @MBaz The thing is, I looked at a few research papers as well, but none of them seemed to use the FFT for the evaluation of the PRF, which lead me to think that maybe it is somehow bad to use the Fourier transform.

Comment: @PessentrauOptiarou well, I think you'll need to refresh what the PRF is, first. Then things will make much more sense.

Comment: @MarcusMüller I see... so how do you normally go about evaluating the PRF? Sorry, for being a little clueless :')

Comment: @MarcusMüller So if I get it right this time, for instance, if I send out a continuous sin wave of bandwidth 2GHz in pulses at 50 pulses per second, then the PRF would be 50 Hz?

Comment: you simply count how many pulses you get per second :) It's rarely something you need to evaluate.

Comment: "a continuous sine wave of bandwidth 2GHz": We might need to work on what "bandwidth" is as wel! A sine wave has zero bandwidth (else it's not sine wave).

Comment: @MarcusMüller Thank you, so much. It cleared up a lot of confusion!